# jQuery click handler does not fire on first click in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm having the following issue exclusively in Safari: I'm attaching a click handler to an input.

If I attach the handler as such, the callback doesn't get called until the second click:

```
this.$applyForm.find("input[type='email']").click( (originalEvent) => {
  originalEvent.preventDefault();
  console.log('this should fire');
});
```

However, if I attach it as such, the callback gets called as expected:

```
this.$applyForm.on('click', "input[type='email']", (originalEvent) => {
  originalEvent.preventDefault();
  console.log('this does fire')
}
```

It doesn't seem like an issue of the HTML not being included, for two reasons:

1) If I log `this.$applyForm.find("input[type='email']")` before the click handler is attached, it logs an element *and* if the element wasn't present when the handler got attached, it would never fire as the handler wouldn't get attached.

2) It's a Safari-only issue.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: I made [the following example](https://jsfiddle.net/o11j6atq/) and it works in Safari 10.0.3 for me. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @E.Sundin finally was able to provide a minimal example. See here: 

https://gist.github.com/ldthorne/f404fd27d02b090a1be9642425073ddf

so far I've been able to reproduce on safari 10.0.3 and 10.1 with the above gist.

Comment: I fixed it by attaching a handler for the `focus` event but... this seems like a bug in Safari's implementation of autofill.

Comment: Interesting bug to say the least!